# Размеры flex элементов

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

Почему box__item-left сжимается при заданной ширине?

```css
.box {
  
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 15px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box__item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 32.439%;
  min-height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  /* padding-right: 0px; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box__item-left {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box__item-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box__item">
    <div class="box__item-left"><img src="" alt="#1"></div>
    <div class="box__item-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut, cum repudiandae itaque dolores praesentium quo qui laudantium explicabo, atque voluptas aliquam.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box__item">
    <div class="box__item-left"><img src="" alt="#1"></div>
    <div class="box__item-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, aut? Ipsum unde, exercitationem impedit necessitatibus explicabo sed. Natus officia, impedit alias.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box__item">
    <div class="box__item-left"><img src="" alt="#1"></div>
    <div class="box__item-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt eius nobis repellat fugiat et maxime reprehenderit, labore distinctio, quidem soluta deleniti.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Твой вопрос звучит так, почему Васю зовут Вася, если его родители назвали Вася...)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что это скорее рекомендуемый размер чем фактический, Flex в зависимости от содержания контента может его растягивать и сужать. Что бы запретить растяжку и сужение пишем в дочерних элементах:

```
flex-shrink: 0;  /* запрещаем сужение */
flex-grow: 0;    /* запрещаем растяжку */
```

в данном случае делаем `flex-shrink: 0`

```css
 * {
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

.box {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 15px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box__item {
  display: flex;
  width: 32.439%;
  min-height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box__item-left {
  width: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box__item-right {
  width: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box__item">
    <div class="box__item-left"><img src="" alt="#1"></div>
    <div class="box__item-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut, cum repudiandae itaque dolores praesentium quo qui laudantium explicabo, atque voluptas aliquam.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box__item">
    <div class="box__item-left"><img src="" alt="#1"></div>
    <div class="box__item-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, aut? Ipsum unde, exercitationem impedit necessitatibus explicabo sed. Natus officia, impedit alias.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box__item">
    <div class="box__item-left"><img src="" alt="#1"></div>
    <div class="box__item-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt eius nobis repellat fugiat et maxime reprehenderit, labore distinctio, quidem soluta deleniti.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Исправить можно добавлением свойства *flex-shrink* со значением *0*. Это свойство определяет, может ли "сжиматься" элемент или нет.

```css
.box {
  
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 15px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box__item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 32.439%;
  min-height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  /* padding-right: 0px; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box__item-left {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
      -ms-flex-negative: 0;
   flex-shrink: 0;
}

.box__item-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box__item">
    <div class="box__item-left"><img src="" alt="#1"></div>
    <div class="box__item-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut, cum repudiandae itaque dolores praesentium quo qui laudantium explicabo, atque voluptas aliquam.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box__item">
    <div class="box__item-left"><img src="" alt="#1"></div>
    <div class="box__item-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, aut? Ipsum unde, exercitationem impedit necessitatibus explicabo sed. Natus officia, impedit alias.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box__item">
    <div class="box__item-left"><img src="" alt="#1"></div>
    <div class="box__item-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt eius nobis repellat fugiat et maxime reprehenderit, labore distinctio, quidem soluta deleniti.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```